# Looking for an alternative solution to finding $E(N)$ for an experiment

Tags: probability, expected-value

I've been given the following problem:

> An infinite number of contestants play the following dice game: The contestants toss a die one by one, the first contestant to get a result either equal or higher than the result of the first dice toss by the first contestant wins the game. $N := $ The number of the winning contestant. $N \geq 2$. Find $E(N)$.

In the official solution the formula used to calculate the mean is $$E(X) =\sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}} P(X>x)$$
I'm aware of it and how to solve the problem using it, but up until then I've mainly used $$E(X) = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}} x \cdot \mathrm{p}_X(x)$$though my attempt has fallen short. How do I know to use the formula used in the official solution as opposed to the formula I'm used to? where is my solution wrong and is there an alternative way? 
**My Attempt**

 I started by trying to find the probability someone will roll higher than the first person, I did so using the 'Entire' probability formula:
$$K = \text{the first player's result} \quad X = \text{any following player's result}$$
$$P(\text{A toss wins}) = \sum_{k=1}^6 P(\text{A toss wins} |K=k) \cdot P(K=k) = \sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{7-k}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{7}{12} $$
$$N \sim \text{Geom}(\tfrac{7}{12}) \implies E[\overbrace{N}^{ N=1 \quad \text{is the 1st player}}] = \frac{1}{p} +1= \frac{12}{7}+1=2.714 \neq 3.45 \quad (\text{which is the correct answer})$$
I've also tried computing the sum directly using the formula I'm familiar with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \cdot \frac{7}{12} \cdot \left(\frac{5}{12}\right)^{n-1}$ and got the same result. I'd love to see if there's a feasable way using these tools I'm familiar with, understanding where I got it wrong, and when is it better to switch up to $E(X) =\sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}} P(X>x)$ instead of using the other one.

Comment: Hard to follow what you wrote...surely the probability of victory is $1$, right?  The game will end someday.  But the concept is fine.  The desired expectation is $\frac 16\times \sum_{k=1}^6 \frac 6{7-k}$

Comment: I'll fix it, I meant the probability of a player's toss beating the first

Comment: Should say:  I am assuming an infinite number of contestants.  Of course it is more complicated if you have finitely many contestants that cycle $\pmod n$.

Comment: Thank you! can you please explain the motivation behind this?  $\frac 16\times \sum_{k=1}^6 \frac 6{7-k}$ should we also add one since N=1 is the original tosser?

Comment: @lulu Must not $1$ must be added to your outcome (because $N\geq2$)?

Comment: Just consider the first roll.  Say it is $k$.  Then there are $7-k$ rolls at least as high as $k$.  Thus there is a $\frac{7-k}6$ chance that a given roll will win.  The expected number of trails is then the reciprocal.  And yes, I computed the expected number of turns.  If you start with contestant $2$, then you must add $1$.

Comment: @drhab  Yes.  I figured the first toss didn't count.  But if the first active contestant is $\#2$ then you must add $1$.

Comment: I understand that $\frac{7-k}{6}$ are the odds of victory and that when calculating the expectation of a geometric distribution we do $\frac{1}{p}$, I struggle with using this knowledge to compute the expectation as you had though: where did the $\frac{1}{6}$ come from and why is there a sum there?

Comment: @Lonimous In short it is applied that: $\mathbb EN=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[N\mid X]]$. First find an expression $f(k):=\mathbb E[N\mid X=k]$. Then $\mathbb E[N\mid X]=f(X)$ and it remains to find $\mathbb Ef(X)$. Here $X$ denotes the first toss result.

Comment: Might be worth making the general comment that the expectation of a game is seldom equal to the payout from the expected play.  For instance, consider the game wherein a fair die is thrown and you get $1$ if it is $6$ and lose otherwise.  The expected payout is obviously $\frac 16$, but the expected roll is $3.5$ and the payout from that is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just reiterating and adding a more detailed solution based on lulu's and drhab's advice:
$$X = \text{The first tosser},$$
$$P(\text{win against x}) = \frac{7-x}{6}.$$
why?
$x=1 \implies P(\{\text{win}\}) = P(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\})=\frac{6}{6},$
$x=2 \implies P(\{\text{win}\}) = P(\{2,3,4,5,6\})=\frac{5}{6},\dots$

so the pattern becomes apparent.
We know then that $$N-1\mid X \;\;\sim\;\; \text{Geom}\left(\frac{7-x}{6}\right).$$
We know that for geometric distribution $\mu = \frac{1}{p}.$ We know that for a discrete random variable $X$:
$$E(f(X)) = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x) \cdot \mathrm{p}_X(x).$$
So:
$$E(N-1)=E\big(E(N-1\mid X)\big)=E\left(\frac{6}{7-x}\right) = \sum_{x=1}^6 \left(\frac{6}{7-x}\right) \cdot \frac16 =2.45,$$
$$E[N]=E[N-1]+1=3.45.$$

Answer (score 1):

First I try to solve the confusion about the difference in formulas for $E(X)$

The formulas are equivalent in this case, as can be seen as follows:

$$P(X>x)= P(X=x+1)+P(X=x+2)+\dots = p_X(x+1)+p_X(x+2)+\dots$$

And now

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty P(X>x) =  (p_X(1)+p_X(2)+p_X(3)+p_X(4)+\dots) + (p_X(2)+p_X(3)+p_X(4)+\dots)+(p_X(3)+p_X(4)+\dots)+(p_X(4)+\dots)+\dots = p_X(1)+2p_X(2)+3p_X(3)+4p_X(4)+\dots.$$

Then about your attempted solution:
I think the problem is in your assumption that $N\sim\mathrm{Geom}(7/12)$. Instead, try to use $E(N)=E(N|K=1)P(K=1)+\dots+E(N|K=6)P(K=6)$.

Edit/extra hint: note that $N_{K=k} \sim \mathrm{Geom}(\frac{7-k}{6})$, maybe with a +1 somewhere

Edit 2:
The equation $E(N) = E(N|K=1)P(K=1)+\dots+E(N|K=6)P(K=6)$ comes from $P(N=n) = P(N=n|K=1)P(K=1)+\dots+P(N=n|K=6)P(K=6)$:
$$ E(N) = \sum_n n P(N=n) $$$$= \sum_n n \big(P(N=n|K=1)P(K=1) + \dots + P(N=n|K=6)P(K=6)\big) $$$$= \sum_n n P(N=n|K=1)P(K=1) + \dots + \sum_n n P(N=n|K=6)P(K=6) $$$$= E(N|K=1)P(K=1)+\dots+E(N|K=6)P(K=6)$$

Comment: can you please explain to me the motivation for this equation? $E(N)=E(N|K=1)P(K=1)+\dots+E(N|K=6)P(K=6)$